# How can I refer/specify VPC from AWS copilot addon file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-copilot

I am creating an (AWS Copilot) addon (inside the `environments` folder) which has the following piece of script creating a security group:

```xml
  SGPostgresDb:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupName: sg-pgdb
      GroupDescription: Allows only postgres traffic
      VpcId: !Ref ?????????
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 5432
          ToPort: 5432
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
```

But I need to somehow refer to the VPC ID. How could I go about it?
In general, how can I refer to the elements specified inside the `manifest.yml`? Besides the VPC, the copilot creates internet gateway, subnets, route table...., so when we create additional resources inside an addon file we might need to refer to VPC or a subnet created by the copilot by `copilot env deploy` command. How can we refer to those elements too?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

@fade2black!
Those environment resources are all `Outputs` of your environment's CloudFormation stack. So other stacks, including workload addons, and manifests can reference them.

```
Outputs:
  VpcId:
    Value: !Ref VPC
    Export:
      Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-VpcId
  PublicSubnets:
    Value: !Join [ ',', [ !Ref PublicSubnet1, !Ref PublicSubnet2, ] ]
    Export:
      Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-PublicSubnets
  PrivateSubnets:
    Value: !Join [ ',', [ !Ref PrivateSubnet1, !Ref PrivateSubnet2, ] ]
    Export:
      Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-PrivateSubnets
  InternetGatewayID:
    Value: !Ref InternetGateway
    Export:
      Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-InternetGatewayID
  PublicRouteTableID:
    Value: !Ref PublicRouteTable
    Export:
      Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-PublicRouteTableID
  PrivateRouteTableIDs:
    Condition: CreateNATGateways
    Value: !Join [ ',', [ !Ref PrivateRouteTable1, !Ref PrivateRouteTable2, ] ]
    Export:
      Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-PrivateRouteTableIDs
  ServiceDiscoveryNamespaceID:
    Value: !GetAtt ServiceDiscoveryNamespace.Id
    Export:
      Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-ServiceDiscoveryNamespaceID
  EnvironmentSecurityGroup:
    Value: !Ref EnvironmentSecurityGroup
    Export:
      Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-EnvironmentSecurityGroup
  PublicLoadBalancerDNSName:
    Condition: CreateALB
    Value: !GetAtt PublicLoadBalancer.DNSName
    Export:
      Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-PublicLoadBalancerDNS
  PublicLoadBalancerFullName:
    Condition: CreateALB
    Value: !GetAtt PublicLoadBalancer.LoadBalancerFullName
    Export:
      Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-PublicLoadBalancerFullName
  PublicLoadBalancerHostedZone:
    Condition: CreateALB
    Value: !GetAtt PublicLoadBalancer.CanonicalHostedZoneID
    Export:
      Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-CanonicalHostedZoneID
  HTTPListenerArn:
    Condition: CreateALB
    Value: !Ref HTTPListener
    Export:
      Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-HTTPListenerArn
  HTTPSListenerArn:
    Condition: ExportHTTPSListener
    Value: !Ref HTTPSListener
    Export:
      Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-HTTPSListenerArn
  DefaultHTTPTargetGroupArn:
    Condition: CreateALB
    Value: !Ref DefaultHTTPTargetGroup
    Export:
      Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-DefaultHTTPTargetGroup
  InternalLoadBalancerDNSName:
    Condition: CreateInternalALB
    Value: !GetAtt InternalLoadBalancer.DNSName
    Export:
      Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-InternalLoadBalancerDNS
  InternalLoadBalancerFullName:
    Condition: CreateInternalALB
    Value: !GetAtt InternalLoadBalancer.LoadBalancerFullName
    Export:
      Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-InternalLoadBalancerFullName
  InternalLoadBalancerHostedZone:
    Condition: CreateInternalALB
    Value: !GetAtt InternalLoadBalancer.CanonicalHostedZoneID
    Export:
      Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-InternalLoadBalancerCanonicalHostedZoneID
  InternalWorkloadsHostedZone:
    Condition: CreateInternalALB
    Value: !Ref InternalWorkloadsHostedZone
    Export:
      Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-InternalWorkloadsHostedZoneID
  InternalWorkloadsHostedZoneName:
    Condition: CreateInternalALB
    Value: !Sub ${EnvironmentName}.${AppName}.internal
    Export:
      Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-InternalWorkloadsHostedZoneName
  InternalHTTPListenerArn:
    Condition: CreateInternalALB
    Value: !Ref InternalHTTPListener
    Export:
      Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-InternalHTTPListenerArn
  InternalHTTPSListenerArn:
    Condition: ExportInternalHTTPSListener
    Value: !Ref InternalHTTPSListener
    Export:
      Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-InternalHTTPSListenerArn
  InternalLoadBalancerSecurityGroup:
    Condition: CreateInternalALB
    Value: !Ref InternalLoadBalancerSecurityGroup
    Export:
      Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-InternalLoadBalancerSecurityGroup
  ClusterId:
    Value: !Ref Cluster
    Export:
      Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-ClusterId
  EnvironmentManagerRoleARN:
    Value: !GetAtt EnvironmentManagerRole.Arn
    Description: The role to be assumed by the ecs-cli to manage environments.
    Export:
      Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-EnvironmentManagerRoleARN
  CFNExecutionRoleARN:
    Value: !GetAtt CloudformationExecutionRole.Arn
    Description: The role to be assumed by the Cloudformation service when it deploys application infrastructure.
    Export:
      Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-CFNExecutionRoleARN
  EnvironmentHostedZone:
    Condition: DelegateDNS
    Value: !Ref EnvironmentHostedZone
    Description: The HostedZone for this environment's private DNS.
    Export:
      Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-HostedZone
  EnvironmentSubdomain:
    Condition: DelegateDNS
    Value: !Sub ${EnvironmentName}.${AppName}.${AppDNSName}
    Description: The domain name of this environment.
    Export:
      Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-SubDomain
  EnabledFeatures:
    Value: !Sub '${ALBWorkloads},${InternalALBWorkloads},${EFSWorkloads},${NATWorkloads},${Aliases},${AppRunnerPrivateWorkloads}'
    Description: Required output to force the stack to update if mutating feature params, like ALBWorkloads, does not change the template.
  ManagedFileSystemID:
    Condition: CreateEFS
    Value: !Ref FileSystem
    Description: The ID of the Copilot-managed EFS filesystem.
    Export:
      Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-FilesystemID
  PublicALBAccessible:
    Condition: CreateALB
    Value: true
  LastForceDeployID:
    Value: "cdb2bccb-136d-4d14-ae90-ad7377cf464e"
    Description: Optionally force the template to update when no immediate resource change is present.
  AppRunnerVpcEndpointId:
    Condition: CreateAppRunnerVPCEndpoint
    Value: !Ref AppRunnerVpcEndpoint
    Description: VPC Endpoint to App Runner for private services
    Export:
      Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-AppRunnerVpcEndpointId
```

See more [here](https://aws.github.io/copilot-cli/blogs/release-v125/#environment-addons) and [here](https://aws.github.io/copilot-cli/docs/developing/addons/environment/)!